# Shannon Entropy

Tags: cryptography, entropy

Shannon Entropy is a measure of randomness of a discrete random variable $X$ which can be defined as
$$H(X) = −\sum_{i=0}^n P(x_i) \log(P(x_i))$$

where each $x_i$ is a possible value of $X$.

For the purposes of cryptographic investigation we consider $X$ to be the output of a random number generator, with $x_i$ denoting all the possible values it could take. By using logarithms in base $2$, we can think of entropy in terms of bits. Some key properties of entropy include:

• Data can have less entropy than the total number of bits, but not more.

• Different length blocks of data can contain the same amount of entropy.

• Identical length blocks of data can contain different amounts of entropy.

This is a very important concept in cryptography, particularly when considering cryptographic keys and passwords. For instance, an $8$ byte key, where the value of each byte is independent and uniformly distributed, can have up to $64$ bits of entropy. We can see this by applying the above formula to each byte to obtain

$$-\sum_{i=0}^{255} P(i) · \log(P(i))=-256·\left(\frac{1}{256}\cdot \log_2{2^{-8}}\right)=8,$$

and then summing this over all the bytes.

However, if those bytes can only take the values 1 or 0, then we see that the entropy in the key
cannot exceed 8 bits, since $−\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\log_2{2^{-1}}+\frac{1}{2}\log_2{2^{-1}}\right)+0+0+\cdots\right) = 1$

a. (i) If each byte in this $64$ bit key has exactly $1$ non-zero bit, and this bit can take any position in the byte with equal probability, how much entropy is there in the entire key?

(ii) The entropy in a stream is preserved under a 1-to-1 map. State a 1-to-1 map from the 64 bit space in (i) such that the resultant stream will have maximal entropy.

If we take 2 independent streams $A$ and $B$ of $64$ bits and concatenate them, then $A||B$ has the sum of the entropy in $A$ and $B$.

b. (i) If $A$ and $B$ are dependent, in that $B = F(A)$, where $F$ is an 1-to-1 map, how much entropy does $A||B$ have?

(ii) If $F$ is not invertible (say a cryptographic hash) how would that affect your answer? Justify your reasoning briefly.

In a cryptographic system, in order for a key to have full entropy, random data is taken from a random source and pooled into a much larger store than the size of the key to be generated. When a key is required, the large quantity of data is processed and compacted to produce the key using a non invertible function. This ensures that if there is relatively little entropy in the collected data, the resultant key will have higher entropy.

Consider the following example system. We have a timer which starts at zero, and has accuracy to $1$ microsecond ($10^{−6}$ seconds). We have a perfect random source which will reset the timer to $0$ at most $1$ second after the previous reset. The value of the timer at reset is read off as a $64$ bit value and added to our entropy pool. When a $64$ bit key is needed, all the $64$ bit timer
values in the entropy pool are bitwise XORed.

Bitwise XORing 2 data streams will result in a stream with greater than or equal entropy to both the input streams.

c. i) How much entropy is in each $64$ bit timer value (use the fact that $2^{10} ≈ 1000$ to help with your estimate).

ii) How many of these values (assuming independence) would need to be concatenated to produce a value with $≥ 64$ bits of entropy.

iii) What is wrong with the suggested XOR combining function? Suggest a better
function to produce a high entropy $64$ bit output.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @copper.hat No, this question is on sample aptitude test for a job application. I do not have enough knowledge in this area to answer it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is mostly about English comprehension, understanding what a byte is and a familiarity with probability (independence, uniform, that sort of stuff). Try a(i) and just apply the formula. Note that all you need to do if figure out the number of (equally likely) possibilities $N$ and then the formula reduces to $\log_2 N$.

Comment: Did you ever get any resolution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

Note that if there are $N$ equally likely possibilities then 
$H(X) = - \sum_{k=1}^N {1 \over N} \log_2 {1 \over N} = \log_2 N$.

a. (i): Each of the 8 bytes has exactly one bit set, so $N=8^8$, so
$H(X) = \log_2 8^8 = 24$.

a. (ii): Since the entropy is preserved by a one to one map, then for any
one to one map, the entropy will be the same. Hence we can choose the
identity map, or if that is unsatisfactory, one could take the map that
reverses the order of the bits in each byte.

b. (i), (ii): If $B=F(A)$, then each message has the form $x||F(x)$ and we see
that $H(A||F(A)) = \sum_k p(x_k||F(x_k)) \log_2 p(x_k||F(x_k)) = \sum_k p(x_k) \log_2 p(x_k) = H(A)$. This holds for an arbitrary $F$.

c. (i): Since the timer has resolution $1\mu S$ and is reset at most every second, we can assume that every value in the range $0,...,10^6-1$ is equally likely, so from the first note, we have $H(A) = \log_2 10^6 \approx \log_2 2^{20} = 20$.

c. (ii): If the $A_k$ are independent, then $H(A_1 || \cdots || A_n) = H(A_1) + \cdots + H(A_n)$, so we look for $n$ that satisfies $20 n \ge 64$, which
has a minimum value of $4$.

c. (iii): I don't have an answer for this. The only criticism I can think
of is that if you request many numbers quickly, they will be the same in many
cases, but I don't see how that would be resolved by using a different
combining function. (Perhaps this is a pseudo-political question, see http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/09/10/torvalds_on_rrrand_nsa_gchq/ :-).) Perhaps the questioner was looking for
hashing as a response? (See https://blog.cloudflare.com/ensuring-randomness-with-linuxs-random-number-generator/ for more of same).

Comment: In part (a), why does $N=8^8$? In part b.(i) Why does $\sum_k p(x||F(x))\log_2 p(x||F(x)) = \sum_k p(x)\log_2 p(x)$? Also, you didn't answer part b.(ii).

Comment: in Part a (i) there are eight bytes and each byte can take one of 8 values. For Part b (i) the probability of message $x||F(x)$ is the same as the probability of message $x$. since $F(x)$ is just computed from $x$. I did answer Part b (ii), whether $F$ is invertible of not is immaterial. (As an aside, I am not required to answer everything! The purpose was to help you not to give a complete answer!)

Comment: Could you explain the following passage from the text please.                                                        For instance, an $8$ byte key, where the value of each byte is independent and uniformly distributed, can have up to $64$ bits of entropy. We can see this by applying the above formula to each byte to obtain

$$-\sum_{i=0}^{255} P(i) · \log(P(i))=-256·\left(\frac{1}{256}\cdot \log_2{2^{-8}}\right)=8,$$

and then summing this over all the bytes. How do we know there are $64$ bits of entropy? Also, where did $2^{-8}$ and $256$ come from?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are having problems with. For a single byte, there are $2^8 = 256$ equiprobable values $0,...,255$ (hence the ${1 \over 256} = 2^{-8}$). The unit of entropy is a bit. The rest is just computation. Look at the first note in my answer.

Comment: In your answer to part (a)ii. Does a 1-to-1 map give maximal entropy?

Comment: Entropy is preserved by 1-1 maps, so no matter what 1-1 map you choose the entropy will be the same. The identity is a 1-1 map. Duplicating the stream is a 1-1 map. Rotating the bits is a 1-1 map. The point is that no information is lost.

Comment: You said that whether the function $F$ is invertible is immaterial. Could you explain this statement.

Comment: b (i) gives a result that shows that $A$ and $A||F(A)$ have the same entropy if $F$ is a 1-1 map. An invertible map is 1-1, so the stream still has the same entropy. The added property of being surjective doesn't change this.

Comment: As an aside, I don't particularly care about the points, but folks usually upvote or accept an answer or provide some indication that it has helped them. I notice that you have accepted none of your answers and have not answered any. I have put some time into both the answer and comments and will limit further engagement on this. I have given a fairly explicit & complete answer.

Comment: For part (b), you wrote $$H(A||F(A)) = \sum_k p(x_k||F(x_k)) \log_2 p(x_k||F(x_k)) = \sum_k p(x_k) \log_2 p(x_k) = H(A)$$. But you could also say $$H(A||F(A))=H(A)+H(F(A))= \sum_k p(x_k) \log_2 p(x_k)+ \sum_k p(F(x_k)) \log_2 p(F(x_k))=\sum_k p(x_k) \log_2 p(x_k)+\sum_k p(x_k) \log_2 p(x_k)=2H(A)$$ Is this correct?

Comment: No. The streams $A, F(A)$ are not independent. Whenever $A$ occurs you know with 100% certainty that $F(A)$ will appear. So the probability of $A||F(A)$ is exactly the same as the probability of $A$. Think of rolling a die, but calling the resulting number out twice. The entropy must be the same.